# How to specify NODE_ENV when using NodeJS CLI app

Tags: node.js, node-commander, nodeenv

I have a CLI app made with NodeJS and I can't figure out how to specify NODE_ENV another way than specify it everytime :

```
NODE_ENV=development myapp
```

I have two env files : .env.development and .env.production

I have a config files that manage the environment :

```
import dotenv from "dotenv";
dotenv.config({ path: `.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}` });

export const config = {
    environment: process.env.NODE_ENV,
    postgres_host: process.env.POSTGRES_HOST,
    postgres_database: process.env.POSTGRES_DATABASE,
    postgres_username: process.env.POSTGRES_USERNAME,
    postgres_password: process.env.POSTGRES_PASSWORD,
    postgres_port: process.env.POSTGRES_PORT,
    telegram_api_key: process.env.TELEGRAM_API_KEY,
    telegram_chat_id: process.env.TELEGRAM_CHAT_ID
};
```

And I use my config object when needed :

```
import { config } from "../config/config.js";

export class Postgres {

    static connect() {
        this.client = new Client({
            host: config.postgres_host,
            database: config.postgres_database,
            user: config.postgres_username,
            password: config.postgres_password,
            port: config.postgres_port
        });
        this.client.connect(function(error) {
            if (error) throw error;
            console.log("Connected to PostgreSQL");
        });
    }
...
```

I'd like to use :

```
myapp
```

And set the chosen environment in my index.js file or somewhere else.

```
#! /usr/bin/env node
import { program } from "commander";
import test from "./commands/test.js";
// Set it by default here maybe ?
program
    .command("test")
    .description("test")
    .action(test);

program.parse();
```

This is my package.json :

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Myapp",
  "main": "bin/index.js",
  "keywords": [
    "cli"
  ],
  "bin": {
    "myapp": "./bin/index.js"
  },
...
```

Do you have an idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a default environment to use in your `config.js` file. When loading your dotenv file, you can specify a default `NODE_ENV` value. For example, if you want to use the `.env.development` file by default if `NODE_ENV` is not specified, you can use the following line to load the dotenv file.

```js
dotenv.config({ path: `.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV || "development"}` });
```

Answer (score 1):

you can easily say:

```
myEnv = process.env.NODE_ENV || "development"
```

and then use `myEnv` instead of `NODE_ENV` like that:

```
import dotenv from "dotenv"
myEnv = process.env.NODE_ENV || "development"
dotenv.config({ path: `.env.${ myEnv }` })
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, works well. Michael Pu answer fits more my current setup.